# D3 changing color of links based on data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to javascript and d3, I've been working with some shared code and I've been trying to modify it.

Here is what I currently have:

https://gist.github.com/erich-kuehn/2770a7c7c1cd633f6b47ebb21b640f68

Its based off of:

http://bl.ocks.org/erikhazzard/6201948

I'm trying to change the color of the links based on a new field I added the csv called status. It seems to run through ok, and if i step through the code it seems to makes some links red and some green, but when its done, they all end up green. Thoughts? Sorry i'm really new at this.

```
 //update
    for(var i=0, len=links.length; i<len; i++){
    if (links[i].status[0][0] === 'red') {
    pathArcs.attr({
            //d is the points attribute for this path, we'll draw
            //  an arc between the points using the arc function
            d: path
        })
        .style({
            stroke: 'red',
            'stroke-width': '2px'
        })
        // Uncomment this line to remove the transition
        .call(lineTransition); 

    //exit
    pathArcs.exit().remove();
        }else{
   pathArcs.attr({
            //d is the points attribute for this path, we'll draw
            //  an arc between the points using the arc function
            d: path
        })
        .style({
            stroke: 'green',
            'stroke-width': '2px'
        })
        // Uncomment this line to remove the transition
        .call(lineTransition);

    //exit
    pathArcs.exit().remove();
}   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`pathArcs`is a selection of elements with data bound to them. When you call a selection's methods (`attr`, `style`, `text`, etc.) it will iterate over all of the elements in the selection. If you provide a static value, each element will be given that value. If you provide a function, then each element will call that function passing it two arguments, the first is the data bound to the element and the second is the element's index in the selection. The return value of this function is what you want to assign for the `attr`, `style`, `text`, etc.

In your code, whenever you are making these `pathArcs` method calls, you are setting the values for every element in the selection. You are ending up with all green elements because the last element in your for loop is making all of them green.

You've probably noticed that the only difference in your if/else statements is where you set the `stroke` color. What this means is that you only have to provide a function for the style's `stroke` value.

```
pathArcs
  .attr({
    d: path
  })
  .style({
    'stroke': function(d) {
      // I don't know if you can just set this based on the
      // value of d.status[0][0] without knowing the possible
      // values of it. Ternary may be unnecessary.
      return d.status[0][0] === 'red' ? 'red' : 'green';
    }),
    'stroke-width': '2px'
  })
  // Uncomment this line to remove the transition
  .call(lineTransition);
```